# Solidworks Flow Simulation the Rotation option missing

Tags: rotation, simulation, analysis, solidworks

I am looking for an assistance to understand, why in SolidWorks 2017, Flow Simulation "wizard - Analysis Type" I have no "Rotation" option?

What I need to do in order to see it?.

The "Rotating Region" is not active, as like gray icon in "Command Manager"

[image: wizard - Analysis Type]

[image: Rotating Region" is not active]

Comment: I think you may be better off asking that on https://engineering.stackexchange.com